# Akka Routing: Recipient Actor was dead

Tags: akka

I am testing Akka and I have this configuration in application.conf.

```
akka.actor.deployment {
    /OperationManagerActor/StatusCheckerActor {
        router = smallest-mailbox-pool
        resizer {
            lower-bound = 1
            upper-bound = 10
            messages-per-resize = 1
        }
    }
}
```

and I got the following exception.

```
2015-05-15 10:55:06 INFO RoutedActorRef:74 - Message [akka.routing.ResizablePoolActor$Resize$] from Actor[akka://GroupOperation/user/OperationManagerActor/$b/StatusCheckerActor#444638645] to Actor[akka://GroupOperation/user/OperationManagerActor/$b/StatusCheckerActor#444638645] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. 
This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

What are my actors dying before my operation is completed?

Answer (score 0):

The initial configuration I used was with ***Akka Resizers***. With `resizers`, the pool will be automatically resized depending on the configuration as normal messages are sent to it. The `messages-per-resize` decides how often a resize is attempted.

In this case, `public int messagesPerResize()` is the number of messages between resize operation. Use 1 to resize before each message.

Hence, I switched to using fixed number of actors (`nr-of-instances` rather than `resizer`) and solved the problem.

```
akka.actor.deployment {
        /OperationManagerActor/StatusCheckerActor {
            router = smallest-mailbox-pool
            nr-of-instances = 10
        }
    }
```